How can I upload a file on Supabase using SSR auth and RLS?
I am trying to upload a file to a supabase bucket that contains RLS policies for insertion:
BEGIN;
ALTER POLICY "Allow users to insert avatar photo" ON "storage"."objects" 
WITH CHECK (((bucket_id = 'avatar'::text) AND ((( SELECT auth.uid() AS uid))::text = owner_id)));
COMMIT;

I am using SSR authentication like it is explained on the documentation.
For the client side supabase client I have this code:
const supabase = () => createBrowserClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!);

And then for uploading the file to the bucket I have this code:
const {error:avatarError} = await supabase.storage.from("avatar").upload(avatar_path,image,{upsert:true});

When I try to execute this operation, I get the following error log on the Supabase side:
{
"event_message": "new row violates row-level security policy (USING expression) for table "objects"",
"id": "8db38f28-ffa1-4106-9a53-08390db10f2b",
"metadata": \[
{
"file": null,
"host": "db-rvjswuemqjmlhfyyopkp",
"metadata": \[\],
"parsed": \[
{
"application_name": "Supavisor",
"backend_type": "client backend",
"command_tag": "INSERT",
"connection_from": "2a05:d018:135e:1602:712:a4de:94b6:40e6:54822",
"context": null,
"database_name": "postgres",
"detail": null,
"error_severity": "ERROR",
"hint": null,
"internal_query": null,
"internal_query_pos": null,
"leader_pid": null,
"location": null,
"process_id": 527687,
"query": "insert into "objects" ("bucket_id", "metadata", "name", "owner", "owner_id", "version") values ($1, DEFAULT, $2, $3, $4, $5) on conflict ("name", "bucket_id") do update set "version" = $6,"owner" = $7,"owner_id" = $8 returning \*",
"query_id": -1540017731558507800,
"query_pos": null,
"session_id": "666d6cf3.80d47",
"session_line_num": 4,
"session_start_time": "2024-06-15 10:29:07 UTC",
"sql_state_code": "42501",
"timestamp": "2024-06-15 10:31:02.911 UTC",
"transaction_id": 23022,
"user_name": "supabase_storage_admin",
"virtual_transaction_id": "6/484678"
}
\],
"parsed_from": null,
"project": null,
"source_type": null
}
\],
"timestamp": 1718447462911000
}

My authentication works fine if it's an action on the server side, but with the browser client I am unable to authenticate myself to Supabase.
